# Python's Deep copy doesn't make copy of dictionary inside new instances of objects

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I want to copy an object (contains a dictionary). I plan to pass this object along in a recursion tree and I want each node in the tree receiving a new copy, not a linked copy.

I discovered that the dictionaries inside the objects "new_t1" and "new_t2" are the same, even though the object ID is different.

Is there an easy way to create a true deep copy of an object, or do I have to write my own to get around it just assigning a pointer to the same dictionary?

hcPartial is a class containing a dictionary and a few other things:

```
class hc:

    dictionary = {'00':[], '01':[], '10':[], '11':[]}
```

Code illustrating failure:

```
#Check making two hypercube copies and independently adding to one of them
nhc1 = copy.deepcopy(hcPartial)
nhc2 = copy.deepcopy(hcPartial)

print "ID 1: ", id(nhc1), "ID 2: ", id(nhc2)
print "D ID 1: ", id(nhc1.dictionary), "D ID 2: ", id(nhc2.dictionary)
print nhc1.dictionary
nhc1.forwardConnect('00','01')
print nhc1.dictionary
print nhc2.dictionary
print nhc1
print nhc2
```

Output:

```
ID 1:  92748416 ID 2:  92748696
D ID 1:  92659408 D ID 2:  92659408
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': [], '01': []}
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': ['01'], '01': []}
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': ['01'], '01': []}
<hypercube.HyperCube2D instance at 0x05873A80>
<hypercube.HyperCube2D instance at 0x05873B98>
```

Intended Output:

```
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': [], '01': []}
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': ['01'], '01': []}
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': [], '01': []}
```

Corrected Output added `__init__()` in class. Works!

```
ID 1:  92746056 ID 2:  92730952
Dict ID 1:  92665728 Dict ID 2:  92680240
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': [], '01': []}
forwardConnect ID 1:  91704656 forwardConnect ID 2:  91704656
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': ['01'], '01': []}
{'11': [], '10': [], '00': [], '01': []}
<hypercube.HyperCube2D instance at 0x05873148>
<hypercube.HyperCube2D instance at 0x0586F648>
```

Comment: What type of class is `hcPartial`?

Comment: It contains a dictionary, edit: normal python dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean it *is* a dictionary, or that it is a class that *contains* a dictionary?   It is an important distinction.  I ask because dictionaries don't have a `forwardConnect` method.

Comment: Ah I see. It contains a dictionary. The forwardConnect(a,b) is the same as dict[a] = b, with the addition of a few legality checks on what a and b can be. I just tried a plain dict[a] = b, and it has the same problem of copying to both dictionaries. Which isn't surprising as they have the same ID. I guess I'll just write a function to copy the dictionary value by value. When someone has a better idea, let me know :D

Comment: Ah the problem turned out being that my class didn't have an __init__() in it. I never knew that was required. Turns out that's all it took. Now the deepcopy works as intended

Comment: `dictionary` in your code is defined as a class attribute i.e., *all* instances of this class share it. If you want each instance to have its own dictionary, you should move its initialization from the class level into a method e.g., `__init__()`: `self.dictionary = ...`

Comment: Oh Okay that is what did it. That makes more sense. So the newly added `__init__() self.dictionary = ...` was overpowering the class attribute of the same name. If you want to add as an answer, I'll accept. ~and maybe edit up the question so it's more clear what the problem actually was now that we know the problem

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> The problem turned out being that my class didn't have an

```
__init__()
```

> in it.
>
> If you want each instance to have its own dictionary, you should move its initialization from the class level into a method:

```
 __init__(): 
 self.dictionary = ...
```

**References**

- [The 'ugliness' of Python | Wit.io, by David Jacobs](https://wit.io/posts/the-ugliness-of-python/)
- [Underscores in Python](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/underscores-in-python)